# Show that both sets are infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose $\lbrace f_i : i \in \Bbb N\rbrace \subseteq \lbrace 0, 1\rbrace^{\Bbb N}$. Prove that there exists $g \in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace^{\Bbb N}$ such that for every $i \in \Bbb N$, the set $\lbrace n\in\Bbb N : g(n) = f_i(n) \rbrace$ and the set $\lbrace n\in\Bbb N : g(n) \ne f_i(n) \rbrace$ are both infinite.

I tried to attack the problem from different angles but I just couldn't find a suitable function $g$.

I am looking only for guidance or hints. *Please don't post full answers*.

Thanks.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: If you have not done so yet, you might want to take this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) where you will learn how to type in your questions. Cheers!

Comment: Ate you familiar with the countable infinite hotel puzzle? Did you ever do it to the point where an infinite number of guests come in each demanding an infinite number of rooms to themselves ? Second hint. Think sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every positive $n $ can be written uniquely as $(\sum_{i=1}^k i)+j;0\le j\le k $.

So use that.

Or if you want use any bijection, $k $, between $\mathbb N\times \mathbb N $ and $\mathbb N $.

For every $i $, there are an infinite number of $k(m,i)=n $.  If we let $g (n=k(m,i))=f_i (n)$ there will be an infinite such $n$, (all $k(\mathbb N\times\{i\}))$ will satisfy.

Just need to expand this to the infinite inequality sets.

Let $j:\{0,1\}\times \mathbb  N^2\rightarrow \mathbb N $ be a bijection.

Define $g (j(0,k,m))=f_m (j(0,k,m))$ for each $m $ there will be infinite values where $g (n)=f_m (n)$

Define $g (j(1,k,m)= f_m (j(1,k,m))+1\mod 2$.  Then for each $m$ there will be infinite values where $g (n)\ne f_m (n)$.

====

If you want to define a precise $g$ consider.

$j: \{0,1\}\times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ via $j(a, k,m) = 2((m-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{i+(m-1)} i)- a$.

$j$ can be proven to be a bijection[$*$].

Define $g(n = j(a,k,m)):= f_m(n)+ a\mod 2$.

For each $m$ there will be an infinite number of $A_m = \{n| n= f(0,k,m); k \in \mathbb N\}$ (all elements of $A_m$ are even by the way) and for all $n \in A_m$, $g(n) = f_m(n)$.  And for each $m$ there will be an infinite number of $B_m = \{n| n = f(1,k,m); k \in N\}$ (all elements of $B_m$ will be odd by the way) and for all $n \in B_m$, $g(n) \ne f_m(n)$.

[$*$] That $j: \{0,1\}\times \mathbb N \times \mathbb N\rightarrow \mathbb N$ should be obvious.  $k \ge 1; m-1 \ge 0;m,n \in \mathbb N$ so $k + (m-1) \ge 1$ and $\sum_{i= 1}^{k+ (m-1)} i \in \mathbb N$ and $m-1 \ge 0$ so $(m-1) +\sum_{i= 1}^{k+ (m-1)}i \in \mathbb N$ and $(m-1) +\sum_{i= 1}^{k+ (m-1)}i \ge 1$ so as $a \le 1; a\in \mathbb N$ then $j(a, k,m) = 2((m-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{i+(m-1)} i)- a\ge  1$ and is a natural number.

Surjective: If $n \in \mathbb N$ then either $n$ is even and $n = 2j$ for some natural $c$ or $n$ is odd and $n = 2c - 1$ for some natural $c$.

The sequence $1 = \sum_{i=1}^1 i < 1 + 2 = \sum_{i =1}^{2}i <..... < \sum_{i=0}^v i < \sum_{i=0}^v i + (v+ 1) = \sum_{i=0}^{v+1} i < ....$ spans the range of all natural numbers.  So there exists a natural $v$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^v i \le c < \sum_{i=1}^{v+1} i$.

Let $m = 1+c-\sum_{i=1}^v i$. Then $1 \le m < v+1$ so $k = v - (m-1) \ge 1$. and $c = \sum_{i=1}^{v=k+(m-1)}i + (m-1)$ and $n = 2((m-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{i+(m-1)} i)- a= j(a,k,m)$ where $a = 0$ if $n$ is even and $a = 1$ if $n$ is odd$.

So $j$ is surjective.

$j$ is injective:

$j(0,b,c)$ is even and $j(1,d,e)$ is odd. so if $j(a,k,m) = j(a',k',m')$ then $a= a'$.

If $b + c < d+ e$ then  $j(a,d,e)= 2((e-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{d+e}i) - a = 2((e-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{b+c} i + \sum_{i=b+c+1}^{d+e}i) -a$

$\ge 2((e-1) + d+e + \sum_{i=1}^{b+c}i) - a$

$> 2(c1 +\sum_{i=1}^{b+c}i) - a = j(a,,b,c)$.

So if $j(a,k,m) = j(a',k',m')$ then $k+m = k' + m'$

If $d < c$ then $j(a,v-d, d) = 2((d-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{v-d + (d-1)=v-c+(c-1)}i) - a$

$<  2((c-1) + \sum_{i=1}^{v-d + (d-1)=v-c+(c-1)}i) - a=j(a,v-c,c)$

So if $j(a,,k,m) = j(a',k',m')$ then $a = a'$; $k+m = k'+m'$ ; $m = m'$ and so $m= m'$

So $j$ is injective.

Comment: Is j the index of f? If it is I didn't get only unique 'n's . What am I missing ?

Comment: Let k:N->NxN be a bijection (my summing is one way to do it but you can use any bijection, even a purely hypothetical one) so that k (n)=(i_n,j_n).  Let g (n)=f_j_n (n).  For each j there are an infinite number of (x,j) and therefor an infinite number of n where k (n)=(x,j) so g (n)=f_j (n) have infinite solutions.  To expand this simply g (2n)=f_j_n (n) (infinite values) and g (2n+1)= opposite (f_j_n (n)) (also infinite values.

Comment: Yes you do get unique ns.  0 yields 1,3,6,10,15,21,28 etc. 1 yields 2,4,7,11,16,22,29 etc. 2 yields 5,8,12,17,23,30 etc. 3 yields 9,13,18,24,31,etc. 4 yields 14,19,25,32 etc. 6 yields 26,33 etc.  j will yield all $(\sum_{i=1}^k i )+ j$ where $k \ge j $.

Comment: But summing is just one way to do it (it's the formal classification of the "diagonal" argument to hand wave a proof that the rationals ar in one to one correspondence with the integers).  Any bijection will do.

Comment: I like this approach. I think you, however, mean $j(0,k,m)$ instead of $j^{-1}(0,k,m)$.

Comment: Oh..  Yeah, I do.  I came up with this is comments and my first was k:N ->NxN. and refering to the the infinite number of $n = f_i(n) as $n \in k^{-1}(N x i)$.  As I wrote it it became clearer that k: {-1,1} x N x N -> N was more direct.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Make $g(4 \cdot k+1) = f_0(4 \cdot k + 1)$...

> and $g(4 \cdot k + 3) \ne f_0(4 \cdot k + 3)$.

...

> This satisfies the condition for $f_0$ and all the even numbers are still available.

Can you see how to continue?

Comment: Not really. I already got so far. My problem is with the fact that I have infinite number of functions. How do I deal with the rest of them?

Comment: You can make $g(8 \cdot k + 2) = f_1(8 \cdot k + 2)$ and also $g(8 \cdot k + 6) \ne f_1(8 \cdot k + 6)$ ...

Comment: I know how to take care of finite number of functions but how can I make sure the n will stay unique when it is infinite. I think I am missing something because I can only see how this can help me for only another function.

Comment: Now that $f_0$ and $f_1$ are taken care of the multiples of 4 are still unused.  So we can assign $16 \cdot k + 4$ and $16 \cdot k + 12$ to $f_2$...

Comment: And then 32*k+8 and 32*k+24 and so on... right?
Now I understand it. Is there any other way to do it? 
maybe more elegant for generalization ?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it, you could also have $g$ coincide with $f_0$ on powers of $2$ but differ on powers of $3$, have it coincide with $f_1$ on powers of $5$ but differ on powers of $7$, etc.

Comment: See my edited answer.  You know {0,1}×NxN has the say cardinality as N so if [0,i,j] <- > n let g (n)=f_i (n) those equal an infinite time for every i.  If [1,i,j]< - > m then let g (m)\ne f_i (m).  Those will not equal an infinite time for every i.  It occurred to me late you don't even have to figure out the bijection because you know one *has* to exist somehow.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n$, let's call $A_n$ the set of $i$ on which we'd like $g(i)= f_n(i)$, and $B_n$ the set of $i$ on which we'd like $g(i)\ne f_n(i)$. Ideally we'd just like all of the $A_n$, $B_n$ to be disjoint from one another, that way we're free to just set $g$ to be whatever we want on those sets, with no chance of our definitions interfering with one another.

So you just need to find a (countable) infinite family of subsets of $\mathbb N$, $C_n$, all of which are disjoint, and then you can set $A_1 = C_1, B_1 = C_2, A_1 = C_3, B_1 = C_4$, and so on.

Can you find a countable family of pairwise disjoint subsets of $\mathbb N$?